# Moving Widgets Over a SparseGridLayout

Tags: python, animation, layout, kivy

As the title says, I'm trying to move widgets across a SparseGridLayout.  The reason is to test displays in high radiation environments.  In previous iterations of the code, I have widgets animated without the SparseGridLayout, but they could not resize.  When I moved to the SparsGridLayout, they disappeared!  After some work, I created a second FloatLayout to be on top of it. Now I see the widgets, but no matter what I do they are stationary!  I have been using code from Kivy Crash Course to get my animation, and modified inclem.net's code for the layout. I'm using kivy 1.9.1 and python 2.7.  Here's some of the code:

```
`<CombinedLayout>:
    SparseGridLayout:


    BlackHorizontalRect
    BlackVerticalRect
.
.
.
 class CombinedLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass
.
.
.
class BlackHorizontalRect(Widget):
    velocity = ListProperty([0, 2])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BlackHorizontalRect,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/60.)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.x += self.velocity[0]
        self.y += self.velocity[1]

        if self.x <0 or (self.x + self.width) > Window.width:
            self.velocity[0] *= -1
        if self.y <0 or (self.y + self.height) > Window.height:
            self.velocity[1] *= -1
class SparseGridLayout(FloatLayout): 


    rows = NumericProperty(1) 
    columns = NumericProperty(1) 
    shape = ReferenceListProperty(rows, columns) 


    def do_layout(self, *args): 
        shape_hint = (1. / self.columns, 1. / self.rows) 
        for child in self.children: 
            child.size_hint = shape_hint 
            if not hasattr(child, 'row'): 
                child.row = 0 
            if not hasattr(child, 'column'): 
                child.column = 0 


            child.pos_hint = {'x': shape_hint[0] * child.row, 
                              'y': shape_hint[1] * child.column} 

        super(SparseGridLayout, self).do_layout(*args) 
class ExampleApp(App): 

    def build(self): 
        labels = [] 
        for i in range(5): 
            for j in range(5): 
                if (i == 0 and j==2) or (i ==1 and j ==1) or (i == 2 and j ==0):
                    labels.append(GridLabel0(row=i, column=j)) 
                if (i == 1 and j == 2) or (i == 2 and j == 1) or (i == 3 and j == 0):
                    labels.append(GridLabel1(row=i, column=j)) 
                if (i == 2 and j==2) or (i==3 and j==1) or (i ==4 and j==0):
                    labels.append(GridLabel2(row=i, column=j))
                if (i == 3 and j ==2) or (i==4 and j==1) or (i==0 and j==0):
                    labels.append(GridLabel3(row=i, column=j))
                if (i == 4 and j==2) or (i==0 and j==1) or (i==1 and j==0):
                    labels.append(GridLabel4(row=i, column=j))   
        layout = SparseGridLayout(rows=3, columns=5) 
        for label in labels: 
            layout.add_widget(label)
        c = CombinedLayout()

        wid1 = BlackVerticalRect()
        wid2 = BlackHorizontalRect()

        c.add_widget(layout, index = 1)
        c.add_widget(wid1)
        c.add_widget(wid2)






        return c


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ExampleApp().run()'
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.